# max value of matrix

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I would like to find the maximum value of one huge matrix I have. I do not need any information of the position, only the value. I have written some easy awk commands, but I struggling with this one.

I suppose I can make a variable run from first field to NF and also from the first line to the last comparing each other, but how can I write it in awk?

Comment: Please edit your post to give an example of matrix.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
 awk 'NR == 1 {maxi=$1;} 
      {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i > maxi) maxi=$i ;} 
      END { print maxi;}' file
```

where

- `NR==1` clause initialize for first line maxi value to first field.
- `NF` is set for each line to number of field
- I assume your field are blank/tab separated, you may whish to use `FS=","` or `FS=";"` in a `BEGIN { }` clause.
- the whole command can be put in a single line, I use several line for readability.

Comment: Better way to intialize maxi with with an actual data point: replace the BEGIN block with `FNR==1 {maxi=$1}`